# angular signalR hub invoke doesnt trigger azure function server

Tags: c#, angular, azure, azure-functions, signalr

I have an azure function app, a SignalR Azure service and an Angular application. My code is:

in Azure Function:

```
[FunctionName("negotiate")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            [SignalRConnectionInfo(HubName = "broadcast")] SignalRConnectionInfo signalRConnectionInfo,
            ILogger log)
        {
            return (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult(signalRConnectionInfo);
        }

        [FunctionName("AddToGroup")]
        public Task AddToGroup(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get")] HttpRequest req,
            [SignalR(HubName = "broadcast")] IAsyncCollector<SignalRGroupAction> signalRGroupActions)
        {
            var userId = new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEnd();
            return signalRGroupActions.AddAsync(
                new SignalRGroupAction
                {
                    UserId = userId,
                    GroupName = userId,
                    Action = GroupAction.Add
                });
        }
```

in angular:

a) SignalRService.ts

```
public startConnection(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl("http://localhost:7144/api").build();
        
      this.hubConnection.start()
        .then(() => {
          console.log("connection established");
          return resolve(true);
        })
        .catch((err: any) => {
          console.log("error occured" + err);
          reject(err);
        });
    });
  }
  public JoinGroup(groupName: string){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
      console.log(this.hubConnection);
      this.hubConnection
        .invoke('AddToGroup', groupName)
        .then(()=>{
          console.log('added to group ', groupName);
          return resolve(true);
        }, err=>{
          console.log(err);
          return reject(err);
        })
    })
  }
```

in App.Component.ts

```
  title = 'Subscriber';
  allMessages: any[] = [];
  allMessagesSubscription: any;
  $groupMessages: Observable<any>;
  groupMessages: any[] = [];
  $groupMessagesSubject: Subscription | undefined;
  userId:string;
  constructor(private signalRService: SignalRService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {
    this.$groupMessages = this.signalRService.GroupMessagesObservable;
  }
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params=>{
      let groupName = params['userId'] ?? 'nil';
      this.userId = groupName;
      if(groupName != 'nil'){
        this.signalRService.startConnection().then(() => {
          this.signalRService.JoinGroup(groupName).then(() => {
            this.signalRService.ListenToGroup();
            this.$groupMessagesSubject = this.$groupMessages.subscribe((d: any) => {
              console.log(d);
              this.groupMessages.push(d);
            });
          }, (err) => {
            console.log(err);
          })
        })
      }
    })
  }
```

When i navigate on the home page of the angular application, the NgOnInit() executes, the startConnection() executes, the Negociate function is successfully triggered on server, then back in angular, the JoinGroup(groupName) function executes, but the `.invoke('AddToGroup', groupName)` does not trigger the breakpoint inside the Function Server, for some reason it is not reached and doesn't log any errors. Any ideas?
Thanks!